# how to create parted disk

Tags: linux, rhel, disk, parted, lsblk

the linux ( OS ) installed on sda

and machine also have additional disk - sdb

```
sdb                8:16   0    20G  0 disk
```

but we want to add two new partitions as sdb1 and sdb2

as the following:

```
sdb                8:16   0    20G  0 disk 
├─sdb1             8:1    0   500M  0 part 
└─sdb2             8:2    0   500M  0 part
```

how to create the disk to be parted with partitions - sdb1 and sdb2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming GNU `parted`, and assuming the snippets you are showing are from the output of `lsblk`, here is a minimal set of actions you can perform to accomplish what you are asking for:

Running `parted` as root, select the device you want to act upon:

```
(parted) select /dev/sdb
```

Create a MBR partition table (no particular reason for choosing this type; in `parted`, type `help mklabel` for a list of available types):

```
(parted) mklabel msdos
```

Then, create the partitions:

```
(parted) unit MiB
(parted) mkpart primary 1 501
(parted) mkpart primary 501 1000
```

`parted` is instructed here to use the mebibyte as unit because that is the default for `lsblk`. This way you can outright type the same numbers posted in your question.

The starting point of the first partition is arbitrarily at 1 MiB because 1) it cannot be at 0 and 2) 1 MiB is a relatively lazy but safe choice for alignment. A discussion on partition alignment seems out of scope here.

You can then check your changes with:

```
(parted) print
```